# Making kexec reboots less painful

Tags: beginner, ruby, parsing, linux

[kexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) is a way for a Linux kernel to directly boot another Linux kernel without going through the usual BIOS startup sequence, which can take several minutes on enterprise servers. The big problem with kexec is that Linux distributions don't set it up for you when you install a kernel, and setting it up yourself is manual and error-prone, so not many people actually use it when rebooting their servers.

I wanted to learn some Ruby, (I've worked through [this Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) but I haven't previously written anything substantial in Ruby) and so I wrote a Ruby script to help automate kexec somewhat. It can simply stage the latest installed kernel for kexec, or it has an interactive mode where you can choose a kernel from a list. It does both of these by searching for the GRUB configuration file, parsing it to get the kernel, initrd and kernel command line, and then calling kexec with these arguments.

My big concern here is with the obvious duplicate code in `process_grub_config` and the functions it calls, `load_kernels_grub` and `load_kernels_grub2`. I know these bits need to be refactored, but I'm not familiar enough with the language to know the best way to go about it. In particular, it's necessary to parse GRUB 1 and GRUB 2 style configuration files differently, and these files can be in different locations depending on Linux distribution.

I also literally wrote this yesterday evening, and I might not have had enough coffee while writing it, so I'm open to suggestions on any other part of the code that might need improvement.

(Note: Because this code is meant to be part of the process of rebooting, I suggest testing in a virtual machine. Run the script with no arguments for a usage statement. I've personally tested it on EL6, EL7, Ubuntu 10.04, 12.04, and Debian wheezy and it should work properly on any Linux distirbution that uses GRUB 1 or GRUB 2.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# kexec-reboot - Easily choose a kernel to kexec

require 'optparse'

# Find a mount point given the device special
def device_to_mount_point(device)
  if File.ftype(device) != "blockSpecial" then
    STDERR.puts("Device #{device} isn't a block device\n")
    return nil
  end
  mount_point = nil
  mounts = open("/proc/mounts").each_line do |mount|
    line = mount.split
    if line[0] == device then
      mount_point = line[1]
      break
    end
  end
  mount_point = "" if mount_point == "/"  # Eliminate double /
  if mount_point.nil? then
    STDERR.puts "Can't find the mount point for device #{device}\n"
    return nil
  end
  mount_point
end

# Find a mount point given the GRUB device and device map
def device_map_to_mount_point(device, device_map)
  dev = device.match(/(hd\d+)/)
  part = device.match(/hd\d+,(\d+)/)
  mount_point = device_map.match(/\(#{dev[1]}\)\s+(.+)$/)
  mount_point_part = 1 + Integer(part[1]) if !part.nil?
  device_path = "#{mount_point[1]}#{mount_point_part}"
  if !File.exists?(device_path) then
    STDERR.puts("Can't find the device #{device_path} from #{device}\n")
    return nil
  end
  device_to_mount_point("#{mount_point[1]}#{mount_point_part}")
end

# Find a mount point given the device UUID
def uuid_to_mount_point(uuid)
  begin
    device = File.realpath("/dev/disk/by-uuid/#{uuid}")
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    STDERR.puts "No such file or directory, uuid #{uuid}\n"
    return nil
  end
  device_to_mount_point(device)
end

# Load the available kernels from the given GRUB 1 configuration file
def load_kernels_grub(config)
  device_map = open("/boot/grub/device.map").read
  entries = Array.new
  config.scan(/title (.+?$).+?root \(([^\)]+)\).+?kernel ([^ ]+) (.+?)$.+?initrd (.+?$)/m).each do |entry|
    mount_point = device_map_to_mount_point(entry[1], device_map)
    name = entry[0].strip
    kernel = "#{mount_point}#{entry[2]}"
    initrd = "#{mount_point}#{entry[4]}"
    cmdline = entry[3].strip
    # Sanity check the kernel and initrd; they must be present
    if !File.readable?(kernel) then
      STDERR.puts "Kernel #{kernel} is not readable\n"
      next
    end
    if !File.readable?(initrd) then
      STDERR.puts "Initrd #{initrd} is not readable\n"
      next
    end
    entries.push({
      "name"    => name,
      "kernel"  => kernel,
      "initrd"  => initrd,
      "cmdline" => cmdline,
    })
  end
  entries
end

# Load the available kernels from the given GRUB 2 configuration file
def load_kernels_grub2(config)
  entries = Array.new
  config.scan(/menuentry '([^']+)'.+?\{.+?search.+?([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}).+?linux(16)?\s+([^ ]+) (.+?)$.+?initrd(16)?\s+(.+?)$.+?\}/m).each do |entry|
    mount_point = uuid_to_mount_point(entry[1])
    name = entry[0].strip
    kernel = "#{mount_point}#{entry[3]}"
    initrd = "#{mount_point}#{entry[6]}"
    cmdline = entry[4].strip
    # Sanity check the kernel and initrd; they must be present
    if !File.readable?(kernel) then
      STDERR.puts "Kernel #{kernel} is not readable\n"
      next
    end
    if !File.readable?(initrd) then
      STDERR.puts "Initrd #{initrd} is not readable\n"
      next
    end
    entries.push({
      "name"    => name,
      "kernel"  => kernel,
      "initrd"  => initrd,
      "cmdline" => cmdline,
    })
  end
  entries
end

# Load a grub configuration file and process it
def process_grub_config
  # TODO: Duplicate code smells, refactor this
  # First, locate the grub configuration file
  # We try GRUB 1 files first
  ["/boot/grub/menu.lst"].each do |file|
    begin
      entries = load_kernels_grub(open(file).read)
      if !entries.empty? then
        if $verbose then
          puts "Read GRUB configuration from #{file}\n"
        end
        return entries
      end
    rescue Errno::EACCES
      STDERR.puts("#{$!}\nYou must be root to run this utility.\n")
      exit 1
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      next
    end
  end
  # Then we try GRUB 2 files
  ["/boot/grub2/grub.cfg", "/boot/grub/grub.cfg"].each do |file|
    begin
      entries = load_kernels_grub2(open(file).read)
      if !entries.empty? then
        if $verbose then
          puts "Read GRUB configuration from #{file}\n"
        end
        return entries
      end
    rescue Errno::EACCES
      STDERR.puts("#{$!}\nYou must be root to run this utility.\n")
      exit 1
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      next
    end
  end
  STDERR.puts("Couldn't find a grub configuration anywhere!\n")
  exit 1
end

def kexec(entry)
  if $verbose then
    print "Staging kernel #{entry['name']}\n"
  end
  fork do
    exec "/sbin/kexec", "-l", "#{entry['kernel']}", "--append=#{entry['cmdline']}", "--initrd=#{entry['initrd']}"
  end
end

def interactive_select_kernel
  entries = process_grub_config

  selection = nil
  loop do
    puts "\nSelect a kernel to stage:\n\n"

    entries.each_with_index do |entry, index|
      selection_number = index + 1
      puts "#{selection_number}: #{entry['name']}\n"
    end

    print "\nYour selection: "
    selection = gets.chomp
    begin
      selection = Integer(selection)
    rescue ArgumentError
      return nil
    end
    break if selection.between?(0, entries.count)
  end

  return nil if selection == 0
  entries[selection - 1]
end

def select_latest_kernel
  entries = process_grub_config
  entries.first
end

options = {}

opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: kexec-reboot [options]"

  opts.on("-i", "--interactive", "Choose the kernel to stage from a list") do |i|
    options[:interactive] = i
  end
  opts.on("-l", "--latest", "Stage the latest kernel") do |l|
    options[:latest] = l
  end
  opts.on("-r", "--reboot", "Reboot immediately after staging the kernel") do |r|
    options[:reboot] = r
  end
  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Extra verbosity.") do |v|
    $verbose = v
  end
end

opts.parse!

if (options[:interactive]) then
  entry = interactive_select_kernel
  if (entry.nil?) then
    STDERR.puts "Canceled.\n"
    exit 1
  end
elsif (options[:latest]) then
  entry = select_latest_kernel
else
  STDERR.puts opts.help
  exit 1
end

if !entry.nil? then
  entry = kexec(entry)

  if options[:reboot] then
    `shutdown -r now`
  end
end
```

This code is now [available on github](https://github.com/error10/kexec-reboot) and future changes will be published there.

---

After this was posted, these changes have been made (which can be seen in the github version):

1. A bug which caused kexec to fail if a previous kernel had already been staged (e.g. via kexec or a kdump crash kernel) has been fixed.
2. A bug which caused the script to fail to find the boot partition on certain older HP ProLiant servers has been fixed.
3. Ruby hashes have been changed to [use symbols as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8189416/1068283), rather than strings.
4. Support was added for systems that boot with UEFI.

---

A number of further changes have been made and are now in github, including most of the suggestions given by 200_success.

In addition, after more extensive testing on a variety of servers (thanks to [ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite)) the following change was made:

- When processing a grub 1 configuration, first assume the kernel can be reached in either / or /boot, before trying to read the device.map file, because device.map is very frequently wrong due to post-installation hardware changes. This issue doesn't affect systems which boot with grub 2.

I'll be doing some more cleanup, and after I've incorporated the rest of the suggestions I'll post the new version for review.

Comment: Could you please repost the bullet points in Revs 3 and 5 as a self-answer? On Code Review, we very much prefer to see all suggestions and explanations of improvements as answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ruby code looks quite good.

---

You have a couple of filehandle leaks.  A typical way to process a file is `open(…) { |file| … }`.  If you call `open` without a block, then you should also `close` the resulting filehandle.

An even simpler approach would be to call static methods such as **`IO::readlines`**.  For example, in `device_to_mount_point`, the following code

> ```
>   mounts = open("/proc/mounts").each_line do |mount|
>     line = mount.split
>     if line[0] == device then
>       mount_point = line[1]
>       break
>     end
>   end
> ```

could be simplified with

```
proc_mounts = Hash[IO.readlines('/proc/mounts').collect { |line| line.split[0..1] }]
mount_point = proc_mounts[device]
```

---

You should **avoid returning `nil` to indicate an error**.  That just burdens the caller with the responsibility to handle a `nil` result properly.  If it's not actually an error, then return an empty string.  If it is an error, you should raise an exception instead:

```
raise ArgumentError.new("Device #{device} isn't a block device")
```

---

It is unusual to see string-to-number conversions written as `Integer(part[1])` in Ruby.  A more common expression would be **`part[1].to_i`**.

---

Here is one way to eliminate the **code duplication** in `process_grub_config`:

```
def process_grub_config
  possible_grub_configs = [
    ["/boot/grub/menu.lst",  :load_kernels_grub],
    ["/boot/grub2/grub.cfg", :load_kernels_grub2],
    ["/boot/grub/grub.cfg",  :load_kernels_grub2],
  ]
  possible_grub_configs.each do |filename, handler|
    begin
      entries = method(handler).call(IO::read(filename))
      if !entries.empty? then
        if $verbose then
          puts "Read GRUB configuration from #{file}\n"
        end
        return entries
      end
    rescue Errno::EACCES
      STDERR.puts("#{$!}\nYou must be root to run this utility.\n")
      exit 1
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      next
    end
  end
end
```

I consider `load_kernels_grub` and `load_kernels_grub2` to be **misnamed, as they aren't actually loading anything,** at least not in the kexec sense.  I suggest a name like `grub1_cfg_kernel_entries` instead.

---

In `kexec`, `fork` and `exec` could just be **a `system` call**:

```
system "/sbin/kexec", "-l", entry['kernel'], "--append=#{entry['cmdline']}", "--initrd=#{entry['initrd']}"
```

The `entry['kernel']` parameter does not need string interpolation.

---

In accordance with the suggestion in the [`kexec(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec) man page, you could just **call `kexec` with no option parameter**, which loads the specified kernel and calls `shutdown`.

Comment: You could have made this six answers and I would happily have given you six upvotes. (Except that Stack Exchange would probably reverse them all, but that's another discussion...) This is a _lot_ of knowledge compressed into a single answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The task is painful because it really is difficult.  It's [difficult](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting) because

> `grub.cfg` is written in GRUB’s built-in scripting language, which has a syntax quite similar to that of GNU Bash and other Bourne shell derivatives.

For example, from my Debian squeeze server, here is an excerpt from `grub.cfg`:

> ```
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
> menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
>         set gfxpayload=1024x768
>         insmod lvm
>         insmod part_gpt
>         insmod ext2
>         set root='(vg-root1)'
>         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 84cc28cc-e54f-43f2-9e62-182d5e6af329
>         echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 ...'
>         linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg-root1 ro console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8r quiet vga=791 text
>         echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
> }
> ```

… and `device.map`:

> ```
> (hd0) /dev/disk/by-id/cciss-3600508b100104439535547344832000b
> ```

Two of the complications are:

- The configuration opted to use the commands `set root=…` and `linux` rather than `root …` and `kernel …`.
- Due to the use of LVM, you won't be able to easily correlate the GRUB device name `(vg-root1)` with the mountpoint by looking in `device.map`.

To claim completeness, you would need to be able to do the inverse of everything that [`grub-mkconfig_lib`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-mkconfig_lib.in?id=2.00) is capable of generating.  A fully general solution would be even more difficult, as it would involve reimplementing a huge chunk of GRUB itself.

Perhaps it would be more advantageous to avoid trying to interpret GRUB's device nomenclature altogether and stay entirely within Linux's device-naming scheme by looking for the `root=…` kernel command-line parameter.  (The [`rdev(8)`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rdev8.html) command from util-linux may be of interest here, if no kernel parameters are passed — which is a rare practice these days.)

Considering the enormity of the task of writing a complete interpreter for `grub.cfg`, I'd be happy if you handled just a limited subset of the configuration language properly.  Ignoring `#Comments` would be a good start.

Comment: I'm tempted to cheat, and actually look in /boot specifically if I wasn't able to figure out what grub was doing, or perhaps even skip the whole thing entirely and _assume_ /boot, and look at the grub configuration only if it isn't found there.

Comment: Also I don't know where you got the idea that I do anything with comments. I am specifically reading `menuentry`, `search`, `linux(16)` and `initrd(16)`.

Comment: You _don't_ want to process any text in the file that is commented out.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. Someone might have manually commented out an entry. Since this is an autogenerated file, I think that's going to be lower priority though. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [symbols as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8189416/1068283) in your hashes. The script is inconsistent with its use of symbols or strings as hash keys, and using symbols saves both time and memory as Ruby symbols are immutable.

When processing a grub 1 configuration, first assume the kernel can be reached in either / or /boot, before trying to read the device.map file, because device.map is very frequently wrong due to post-installation hardware changes. This issue doesn't affect systems which boot with grub 2.

```
# Scan directories to find the one containing the given path
def locate_kernel(kernel)
  ["", "/boot"].each do |dir|
    STDERR.puts "Looking for #{dir}#{kernel}\n" if $verbose
    return dir if File.exists?("#{dir}#{kernel}")
  end
  raise Errno::ENOENT
end

# Load the available kernels from the given GRUB 1 configuration file
def grub1_kernel_entries(config)
  device_map = IO.read("/boot/grub/device.map")
  entries = Array.new
  config.scan(/title (.+?$).+?root \(([^\)]+)\).+?kernel ([^ ]+) (.+?)$.+?initrd (.+?$)/m).each do |entry|
    begin
      # Try hard-coded locations, works 99.9% of the time
      mount_point = locate_kernel(entry[2])
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      # Fallback to reading grub1 device.map, which is often wrong
      mount_point = device_map_to_mount_point(entry[1], device_map)
    end
    #.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I get that the objective here is to do it with Ruby, but if all you are looking to do is kexec based reboot, this is a little more complicated than necessary. You may find the script in this article handy for a [simple fast reboot using kexec](https://altechnative.net/warm-reboot-on-linux-with-kexec-remember-qemm/). The bash is trivial enough to easily convert to Ruby.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  While your suggesting may well be a good one, links rot over time and this answer doesn't really review the code.  If you could summarize the differences between the approach you suggest and the posted code, it could be a better answer.